# jquery using on('submit') with two forms but only one works properly

Tags: jquery

I am still learning javascript and jquery, mainly by trial and error and I now have a problem that I haven't been able to resolve by reading similar questions and answers (my usual way of learning). This problem concerns the use of jquery to submit forms.

I have a single html page with a main form (msg_form) that is working. I recently added a 'widget' with another form (PMwdgt_form). Both forms perform similar actions, though not identical, so I added extra functions in jquery to handle the 'widget'. The page and widget forms are dynamic.

The main form continues to work correctly but when I submit the 'widget' form I get a page reload (normal submit activity) with a query string appended to the URL as if the event has not been triggered. Also, I expect the 'enter' key to perform as a submit (as it does on the main form) but it only enters a new line. The page and widget are built dynamicaly.

I have checked in Firefox inspector and found that the 'Events' list shows "submit on 2 nodes in jquery-1.11.1.min.js" where there was only one prior to the widget. I have tried using jquery-latest.min.js but the problem still exists. Sorry, I don't have a demo of it.

Any help you can give me to get both form submitting through jquery would be very much appreciated.

main page form...

```
<form id='msg_form'>
  <input id='chnl' name='chnl' type='hidden' value='$_SESSION[chnlid]'>
  <div class='msgbox left'>
    <textarea style='min-width: 635px; min-height: 45px;' name=message id=message placeholder='Type your message' title='Hold SHIFT and press ENTER for a new line'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class='sendbtn right'>
    <button class='send' id='msg_send' type=submit>Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

main page js...

```
$("#msg_form").on("submit",function(){
  t=$(this);
  var val = $('textarea#message').val();
  var val1 = $('input#chnl').val();

  if(val!=""){
    $.post("send.php",{msg:val,chnl:val1},function(){
      load_new_stuff();
      t[0].reset();
    });
  }

  return false;
});

$('#message').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    document.getElementById('msg_send').click();
    return false;
  }
});
```

widget form...

```
<form id='PMwdgt_form'>
  <div class='msgbox'>
    <textarea name=PMw_msg id=PMw_msg placeholder='Hit ENTER to send - Hold SHIFT and press ENTER for a new line.'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class='sendbtn'>
    <input type=hidden id='PMw_msgto' name=msgto value='$frmid'>
    <button class='send' id='PMw_msg_send' type=submit>Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

widget js...

```
$("#PMwdgt_form").on('submit', function(){
  t=$(this);

  var val = $('textarea#PMw_msg').val();
  var val1 = $('input#PMw_msgto').val();

  if(val!=""){
    $.post("PMsend.php",{msg:val,mto:val1},function(){
      t[0].reset();
    });
  }

  return false;
});


$('#PMw_msg').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    document.getElementById('PMw_msg_send').click();
    return false;
  }
});
```

All js snippets above are within the `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Sorry I understand there's no demo. But can you put all the code in a working format by pressing `Ctrl + M` or using http://jsbin.com?

Comment: Change `document.getElementById('PMw_msg_send').click();` to `$('#PMw_msg_send').click();`.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar sorry, this is my first question. When should I press Ctrl+M?

Comment: When you are **[edit]ing** the post, in the edit mode, you can do it. If you are confused, just got to http://jsbin.com and paste your code. `:)` Also check if the below solution fixes it. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Edited the code but no change, form still submits without running jquery and enter key still puts in a new line.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the suggestion below to replace the javascript selector with the jQuery selector (which I agree with), I could not find anything else wrong with your code. However, since your second form is in a widget of some sort, I'm assuming you're loading this in later at some point? So it could be that the `<form id="PMwdgt_form">` hasn't loaded yet. You'll have to put the jQuery that relates to this form below the HTML where this form is added to the DOM, and you may also want to add a `$(document).ready()`. Without changing anything else to your code, this JSFiddle is working: https://jsfiddle.net/ecbxgpkk/1/ So I'm pretty sure it has something to do with loading of the form, and loading of the jQuery that 'attaches' to this form. If your widget is in some sort of other HTML page, or is loaded in later, make sure that the jQuery that relates to it loads AFTER the form has been loaded into the DOM.

EDIT: I have changed your code completely. Here's the **working** code: 
Note that, for demo purposes, I changed the $.post with something much simpler. You'll have to change this back yourself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#msg_form").on("submit", function() {
    t = $(this);
    var val = $('textarea#message').val();
    var val1 = $('input#chnl').val();

    if (val != "") {
      $('.output').append(val + ' sent to channel: ' + val1 + '<br>');
    }

    return false;
  });

  $('#message').bind("enterKey", function(e) {
    $('#msg_send').click();
  });
  $('#message').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");
   $('#message').val('');
    }
  });

  $("#PMwdgt_form").on('submit', function() {
    t = $(this);

    var val = $('textarea#PMw_msg').val();
    var val1 = $('input#PMw_msgto').val();

    if (val != "") {
      $('.output').append(val + ' sent to person: ' + val1 + '<br>');
    }

    return false;
  });

  $('#PMw_msg').bind("enterKey2", function(e) {
    $('#PMw_msg_send').click();
  });
  $('#PMw_msg').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey2");
   $('#PMw_msg').val('');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='msg_form'>
  <div class='msgbox left'>
    <textarea style='min-width: 635px; min-height: 45px;' name='message' id='message' placeholder='Type your message' title='Hold SHIFT and press ENTER for a new line'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class='sendbtn right'>
    to: <input id='chnl' name='chnl' type='text' value='CHANNEL'>
    <button class='send' id='msg_send' type=submit>Send</button>
  </div>
</form><br>

<form id='PMwdgt_form'>
  <div class='msgbox'>
    <textarea style='min-width: 635px; min-height: 45px;' name='PMw_msg' id='PMw_msg' placeholder='Hit ENTER to send - Hold SHIFT and press ENTER for a new line.'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class='sendbtn'>
    to: <input type='text' id='PMw_msgto' name='msgto' value='PERSON'>
    <button class='send' id='PMw_msg_send' type=submit>Send</button>
  </div>
</form><br>

Output:<br>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The widget is loaded with the main page. Originally it wasn't but I found the on('submit') event wasn't being bound so I already made that change. However, I will try moving it to the start of the page to test the theory. All the js snipppets are already within the document.ready() function. All jquery scripts are loaded in the head tag.

Comment: You were right! I have just tried moving the widget's position and it worked. I think the problem is reloading the widget. It would seem to me that the event binding is 'dropped' if the target form is re-loaded after the document has been loaded. The main page never changes so it wasn't apparent. Now, how do I mark this as solved?

Comment: Cool, glad that it's fixed! Please also have a look at my code for my alternative solution to binding of the ENTER key, because I think this works a little bit better! You should be able to select my answer as the correct one after a little time has passed. That would be the way to cose it. You can also upvote it if you have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the re-write, I'll be substituting it for my weaker efforts. :)